# Only showing those that Return true from a FOR AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, loop

I am searching a data extension based on an ID and returning vairables and a link from those.

I was able to get it to pull all the required data and show correctly. However when I try to add a condition for only those that equal true to show it errors out and have tried playing around with the conditions and cant seem to get it working.

Here is the code that works and brings in all the links:

```
%%[ var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @MasterID, @counter

set @MasterId = MasterID
set @rows = LookupRows("Application__c_Salesforce","ID__c", @MasterID) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 


if @rowCount > 0 then 

for @counter = 1 to @rowCount do 
set @row = row(@rows, @counter)
set @ReadyFor = field(@row,"Ready_for_Check__c") 
set @ApplicationID = field(@row,"Application_Link__c") ]%%
<center>&#8226; App %%=v(@counter)=%%: %%=v(@ApplicationID)=%%<br></center>

%%[ next ]%% 

%%[ else ]%% 

No items to display 

 %%[ endif ]%%
```

However when I try and get only those that are True to show is when the errors start

```
%%[ var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @MasterID, @counter

set @MasterId = MasterID
set @rows = LookupRows("Application__c_Salesforce","ID__c", @MasterID) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 


if @rowCount > 0 then 

for @counter = 1 to @rowCount do 
set @row = row(@rows, @counter)
set @ReadyFor = field(@row,"Ready_for_Check__c") 
set @ApplicationID = field(@row,"Application_Link__c") ]%%
 if @ReadyFor is True then
 &#8226; App %%=v(@counter)=%%: %%=v(@ApplicationID)=%%<br>
 %%[ else ]%% 
 %%[ endif ]%%

%%[ next ]%% 

%%[ else ]%% 

No items to display 

 %%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `if @ReadyFor is True then` statement is outside of your AMPscript block.  Should be inside:

```ampscript
%%[ 

var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @MasterID, @counter
set @MasterId = AttributeValue("MasterID")
set @rows = LookupRows("Application__c_Salesforce","ID__c", @MasterID) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 

if @rowCount > 0 then 

  for @counter = 1 to @rowCount do 

    set @row = row(@rows, @counter)
    set @ReadyFor = field(@row,"Ready_for_Check__c") 
    set @ApplicationID = field(@row,"Application_Link__c")

    if @ReadyFor then
    ]%%

      &#8226; App %%=v(@counter)=%%: %%=v(@ApplicationID)=%%<br>
   
    %%[ 
    else ]%% 
   
    %%[ 
    endif ]%%

  %%[ 
  next @counter ]%% 

%%[ 
else ]%% 

No items to display 

%%[ 
endif ]%%
```

I'd also add [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue) around your naked `MasterID` personalization string.

If that doesn't work, I'd output the value of `@ReadyFor` and check to make sure it's actually a Boolean value.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. 

It is no longer giving the classic huge red error screen so thats good. However it is simply showing blank right now. Any ideas why? 

I have done an Output beside my first snippet to confirm there was Trues and Falses coming in.

Comment: I added the copy part to the Else after the True check and it displays all the results, so it must not be finding the Trues specifically maybe ? Also double checked  the Ready_for_Check__c is a Boolean Field

Comment: Quick play around and switched to if @ReadyFor == "True" then and it looks like it is working thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I generally use 1 or 0 for true/false, but you should be able to reference those values without the single quotes.  Here's a few variations: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/WNQfxtfl